# Water heater relief valve dripping

Tags: water-heater

Canada, gas-fired high-efficiency water heater installed 2013 i.e. 4 years ago (according to the tag), simple system (no expansion tank, no pressure regulation), city water.

I just noticed a small puddle of water under the relief valve discharge tube. The house has been vacant since I took possession in October (now about 5 months). The main water supply has been on until a couple of weeks ago when the kitchen was renovated and the supply has been turned on and off, and some lines partly drained a number of times for plumbing work.

Is this a sign of a developing leak in the relief valve? Is it a temporary side-effect of the system being turned off, at least partly drained, turned back on, etc.? The tank is a rental. Do I need to get the rental company in to service it, or is it normal for the relief valve to respond in this way to the pressure changes brought about due to the plumbing work?

Comment: Normally it's a T&P or temperature AND pressure relief.  Turning off the water supply without shutting down the heating source may cause what you are describing.   If it continues to drip under normal usage then the relief valve needs replacement.  It's an inexpensive part.

Comment: You might want to call the rental company and ask them whether they would prefer to fix it or if you should do it yourself.

Comment: Does the outflow line of the relief valve discharge tube go outside onto the ground? Is that where the small puddle is? Some high-efficiency gas-fired water heaters condense the water vapor in the flue and must drain it somewhere. Where and how is it drained? Is there any possibility that the water drip you see is this condensate water and not from a leaking P&T relief valve?